# Google smart home python app won't link but completes OAuth 2 flow

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, arduino, iot, google-smart-home

I'm working on a smart universal remote app written in python to control my 'dumb' tech at home.  Moving it to an actual smart home device from an iftt trigger to my application controlling the arduino.

It's there in the google home app under works with google, go through the OAuth2 flow and all but it never shows as linked afterward.

I can get through oauth2flow but I am running into issues with agent_user_id.  I can't seem to get anything but requested entity not found on a request sync, sending a synce response unprompted does nothing.

I've implemented user account linking 2 ways in the past 2 days but all I can get is requested entity not found.  I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere.  I have a service account making the request sync and am linking the user with oauth2flow but all I get is to the end of my flow and no linking.  Both go all the way to the final call which is a request sync (or sync in testing) and none work; request sync returning 404 requested entity not found as above.

I can see the homegraph api being hit in the console and erroring out as well as making it through o auth flow.

I'm sure I'm missing something with the agent_user_id.  My google action is set up (works to fulfill the above).  This is my first google home project.  Moving my google home ardiuino ir remote off of iftt webhooks

The app shows up in works with google but does not show up as linked after completing the flow

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

‘Request entity’ not found during the linking process could indeed indicate an issue with locating or recognizing the specified entity.

Here are a few things to check:

Agent User ID Consistency: Ensure that the agent_user_id is consistent throughout the linking process, from the OAuth flow to the linking request.

Verify Permissions: Ensure that your service account has the correct permissions to interact with the Google Home API.

User Account Linking Configuration: Review your OAuth configuration and make sure it includes the necessary scopes and permissions for user account linking.

Linking Endpoint URLs: Confirm that the endpoint URLs specified in your linking configuration match the actual URLs where your application is expecting the linking requests.

Check OAuth Redirect URIs: Ensure that the redirect URIs in your OAuth configuration match where your application is expecting the callback.

We highly suggest checking Google’s [Smart Washer codelab](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer#1) which can provide valuable insights and examples for OAuth implementation within the context of a smart home project.